# Update array roles of Meteor.users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor roles of alanning, https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

I am doing the part where the user will be added to a team and have an access. 
The problem is in this code,

```
Meteor.users.update('profile.team':team.name,{$pull:{'roles["default-group"]':access}});

 Meteor.users.update('profile.team':team.name,{$push:{"roles['default-group']":access}});
```

In the default-group role of a user, I need to add/remove the access.

These lines are not working. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you not supposed to use below given code to perform add or remove operation?

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(joesUserId, ['manage-team','schedule-game'], 'manchester-united.com')
```

For deleting:

`Roles.setUserRoles(targetUserId, [], group)`